# Where can I find detailed damage stats for bodkin vs. broadhead arrows?

Tags: chivalry-medieval-warfare

From chatting with people on public games (in Chivalry), I was told that broadhead arrows are the best option to use.

But then again, what if most of the enemy team were heavily armored knights?

This led me to wonder, what are the exact damage stats for each arrow vs. each class type in the game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ami8d_HZmYHsdDRzc1Byb3ItVWNXSFR1SURHN29TZnc#gid=1) is a link to a spreadsheet with all the stats.

As I expected, Bokdin arrows have a significant advantage (in general) over broadhead arrows. Unless you are targeting archers exclusively, bodkin arrows will give most damage.

the damage done to Vangaurds by bodkin is significantly higher than broadhead (the difference is larger than that done on archers with broadhead vs bodkin)

Comment: another point of view is that broadhead are more effective in combat because of the fact that warbows with broadhead arrows can be used to one-shot kill both MAA and archer enemies. Also, since heavier classes take multiple shots to kill anyways, the decrease in damage done is insignificant enough in battle (because archers mostly don't kill heavy units unless they are already weakened).